# Storing Chinese Characters in mysql

Tags: mysql, chinese-locale

Im trying to store chinese characters to mysql database but am unable to.

Changed characterset for the table to **utf8** and **utf8mb4**

Table looks something like this

```
id  bigint(20)  NO  PRI     auto_increment
version bigint(20)  YES         
country varchar(255)    YES         
englishName varchar(255)    YES
chineseName varchar(255)    YES
```

Trying to alter the chineseName cell to chinese using the following query.

```
UPDATE nametable` SET `chineseName` = '上海' WHERE (`id` = '1');
```

Still get and error as follows.
`ERROR 1366: 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xB8\x8A\xE6\xB5\xB7...' for column 'code' at row 1`

Comment: Please provide and example insert statement and your tables schema

Comment: How did you change the character set for the table? You may have changed the default character set without converting the existing columns.

Comment: Used the following code. Havent changed each column individually.`ALTER TABLE nameTable
CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 , COLLATE = utf8mb4_bin ;`

Comment: @BillKarwin individually changing each columns character set seems to work. I just assumed changing it for the table would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered in comments that this is what you did to change the character set:

```
ALTER TABLE nameTable CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 , COLLATE = utf8mb4_bin
```

This only changes the table's default character set and collation. It doesn't change the existing columns, it only applies to future columns you add to the table.

Here's what the table looks like after this change:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE nameTable\G

CREATE TABLE `nameTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `englishName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `chinesename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

You can see that the table's default (on the last line) is changed, but each column still has the old character set.

You can convert existing columns one by one, or else you can convert them all at once this way:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE nameTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE nameTable\G

CREATE TABLE `nameTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `englishName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `chinesename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

Now all the columns have been converted.

MySQL has some strange rules about when each column shows its character set. See [How does MySQL determine when to show explicit character set & collation values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679576/how-does-mysql-determine-when-to-show-explicit-character-set-collation-values/67679720#67679720)